# Storing appended elements to localStorage

Tags: append, local-storage

I'm a teacher and creating a page to organize my lesson plans. There should be the ability to add new lessons (li) and new weeks (ul). The lessons are sortable between each of the weeks. Each newly added item will then be saved to localStorage.

So far, I'm able to create the lessons and new weeks. The sortable function works. The save function works... except that it will not save any of the new weeks (ul). When I refresh, the new lessons (li) are still on the page, but the new weeks (ul) are gone.

```
  $("#saveAll").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var listContents = [];
    $("ul").each(function(){
       listContents.push(this.innerHTML);
    })
    localStorage.setItem('todoList', JSON.stringify(listContents));
  });

  $("#clearAll").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    localStorage.clear();
    location.reload();
  });

  loadToDo();

  function loadToDo() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('todoList')){
        var listContents = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todoList'));
        $("ul").each(function(i){
          this.innerHTML = listContents [i];
        })
    }
  }
```

I created a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mnaputi/pm06r2bz/4/).

You can click the "Add New Week" button and then click the "Create Lesson" button and drag the new lesson into one of the weeks. After clicking "Save All", only the first week is saved.

I can't seem to figure out what's missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's saving correctly, but since the page only has one `<ul>` element initially, that is the only one that gets populated in `loadToDo()`.  (`listContents` has more than one element, but `$("ul").each(...)` only iterates over one element.)

There is a quick band-aid you can use to resolve this.  Refactor your `#new-week-but` click handler into a named function:

```
function addNewWeek() {
    var x = '<ul class="sortable weeklist"></ul>';
    $(x).appendTo('.term').sortable({connectWith: '.sortable'});
}

$('#new-week-but').click(addNewWeek);
```

Then add this block after you fetch the array from storage but before you enumerate the `<ul>` elements:

```
var i;
for (i = 2; i < listContents.length; ++i) {
    addNewWeek();
}
```

This will add the required number of `<ul>` elements before attempting to populate them.

I chose to initialize `i` to two because this creates two fewer than the number of elements in `listContents`.  We need to subtract one because there is a `<ul>` in `.term` when the page loads, and another because the `<ul id="new-lesson-list">` contents also get saved in `listContents`.  (Consider filtering that element out in your `#saveAll` click handler.)

(Note that this requires merging all of your `$(document).ready()` functions into one big function so that `addNewWeek()` is visible to the rest of your code.)

---

Suggestions to improve code maintainability:

1. Give each editable `<ul>` a CSS class so that they can be distinguished from other random `<ul>` elements on the page.  Filter for this class when saving data so that the "template" `<ul>` doesn't get saved, too.
2. Remove the one default editable `<ul>` from the page.  Instead, in your `loadToDo()` function, add an `else` block to the `if` block and call `addNewWeek()` from the `else` block.  Also, call it if `listContents.length == 0`.  This will prevent duplicating the element in the HTML source (duplication is bad!) and having to account for it in your load logic.

If you implement both of these then you can initialize `i` to 0 instead of 2 in my sample code, which is a lot less weird-looking (and less likely to trip up future maintainers).

Comment: Thanks. This works. I'm curious to know, though, what would be a better path to follow in order to accomplish this as you said this is just a band-aid?

Comment: @mnaputi I added some suggestions to the bottom of my answer.